# How to work with @ManyToMany on Spring using Rest Controller and JSON

Tags: json, hibernate, rest, spring-data-jpa, spring-restcontroller

**The context:**
I'm working with Spring Boot as the back end from my application. Everything is looking fine until now. I have an Entity:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "tb_dish")
public class DishEntity extends AuditableEntity {

    private BigDecimal salePrice;
    private String picture;
    private String description;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "tb_dishes_products")
    private List<ProductEntity> products;

    @ManyToOne
    private CategoryEntity category;

    // getters and setters
}
```

which is responsible to link my "dishes" to my "products". I wrote a Service to store the Dish Entity on my DB:

```java
@Service
public class DishService implements IService<DishEntity> {

    @Autowired
    private DishRepository dishRepository;

    @Override
    public DishEntity create(DishEntity entity) {
        try {           
            return this.dishRepository.save(entity);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            return null;
        }
    }

    // other methods
}
```

and finally the Rest Controller class responsible to receive the HTTP request:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/apis/dishes")
public class DishController implements IController<DishEntity> {

    @Autowired
    private DishService dishService;

    @Override
    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<?> create(@RequestBody DishEntity entity) {
        DishEntity create = this.dishService.create(entity);

        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(create); 
    }

    // other methods
}
```

The JSON body looks like this:

```js
{
    "salePrice": "30.00",
    "picture": "TBD",
    "description": "The description goes here",
    "category": {
        "id": 32
    },
    "products": [
        {
            "product": {
                "id": 29
            }
        },
        {
            "product": {
                "id": 30
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**The Problem**:
I've researched a lot on internet but I didn't have success trying to solve my problem. Everytime that I try to insert a new "dish" an exception is thrown:

> org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: br.com.barexpert.entity.ProductEntity; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: br.com.barexpert.entity.ProductEntity

*Note: The "products" that I'm trying to link with the "dish" are already inserted on my database.*

**I know a couple things**:

1. A `Transient` entity is not `Managed` by the Hibernate and first I need to transform those transient entities into a managed elements. So the question is how can I do that for a `List`? How can I make the an the List entities become managed considering that I already have those elements within my database?
2. If I use the property `CascadeType.ALL` the Hibernate inserts new products containing `null` values.  If I try to save my products list using the `saveAll(List<S> entities)`, the same behavior occurs.

If my question is not good enough, please help me to improve it!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I want to share with you how I've solved my problem:

I've changed my JSON from:

```js
{
    "salePrice": "30.00",
    "picture": "TBD",
    "description": "The description goes here",
    "category": {
        "id": 32
    },
    "products": [
        {
            "product": {
                "id": 29
            }
        },
        {
            "product": {
                "id": 30
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

To this:

```js
{
    "salePrice": "30.00",
    "picture": "TBD",
    "description": "The description goes here",
    "category": {
        "id": 32
    },
    "products": [
        {
            "id": 29
        },
        {
            "id": 30
        }
    ]
}
```

I don't know if this is the best practice but it worked :)